# $A,B$ Matrices $5{\times}5$, $p(B)<p(A)$, dim solution space $Bx=0$ is $ 2$, prove: $BA \neq 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, homogeneous-equation

$A,B$ Matrices $5{\times}5$, $p(B)<p(A)$

Solution space of $Bx=0$: $Sp\{(1,-2,5,0,1),(4,0,-3,4,1)\}$

Prove: $BA \neq 0$.

*$p(A) = \operatorname{rank}(A)$

---

My attempt: (stuck in the middle)

We know that:

$\#n-p(B)=\dim P$

Where:

#n - num of varaibles

$p(B) - \operatorname{rank} B$

$\dim P$ - the dimension of the solution set for $Bx = 0$

Therefore, we conclude: $p(B) = 3$

$\Rightarrow 3<p(A) \leq 5 = 4 \ or \ 5$

I though maybe i could conclude somehow that $A$ is invertible ,therefore $BA \neq 0$, but could'nt make it. (The rank(A) may be 4).

hint?

### *Edit:

As suggested by the answer i will write the way i understood it for people that will look at this question in the future.

If $p(A) = 5$, therefore A invertible, therefore for every B square matrix $5x5$: $BA \neq 0$ (invertible matrix proteprties).

If $p(A) = 4$, We will assume $BA = 0$ and get to a contradiction.

If $p(A) = 4$, there are 4 independent colums in A.

Choose 4 different vectors$x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$, such that $Ax_1$ represent the first independent column, $Ax_2$ the second independent and so on.

We assume $BA = 0$, therefore, multiply from the right by $x_1$ get: 
$BAx_1 = 0$ its a unique, independent solution for $Bx = 0$.

Again, take $BA = 0$, multiply from the right by $x_2$ we get:
$BAx_2 = 0$, its another independent solution for $B_x = 0$

And so on.

We get therefore 4 independent solutions for $Bx = 0$.

But we know that the dimension of the solution set of $Bx = 0$ is 2.

Contradiction.

$BA \neq 0$.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Could you add the definition of $p(A)$? And $\# n$? We should have $n=5$, right?

Comment: Ok i did it, thanks for the comment. $p(A) = rank(A)$

Comment: And yea, #n = num of variables, therefore $n = 5$

Comment: Ah, I see. I was confused because you write "The "rank(A)" may be $4$" in the last sentence, and not $p(A)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If rank of $A$ is $5$ and $BA=0$, it implies that $A$ is invertible and hence $B=0A^{-1}=0$, which is a contradiction, because nullity of $B$ is not $5$.

If rank of $A$ is $4$, then

$$B(Ax)=0\forall x\in\Bbb R^5$$
Hence, nullity of $B$ is atleast the rank of $A$, which is a contradiction (because kernel of $B$ contains atleast as many linearly independent vectors, as in the column space of $A$).

Comment: If $rank(A) = 5$ then for every square $5x5$ matrix $BA \neq 0$ thats what i though. 

for $rank(A) = 4$ i have a problem, as i wrote, and i cant use the kernel, because we didnt learn it yet officially.

Comment: The kernel of $B$ is the solution set of equation $Bx=0$. Don't use the word, if you don't want to.

Comment: Nullity is the dimension of kernel, as you yourself have written in your question.

Comment: I try to understand but i dont get what you have done. can you explain more about the part $B(Ax)=0$ that you did?

Comment: Do you understand column space of a matrix?

Comment: What do you mean understand? that the space of columns = space of rows, that the rank of columns = rank of rows... what exactly?

Comment: OK, that is very good. Now take $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$ four vectors such that $Ax_1,Ax_2,Ax_3,Ax_4$ are linearly independent. These comprise four linearly independent solutions of $Bx=0$, which is not possible, because only solutions of that are in the span of two given vectors.

Comment: You mean, choose the 4 linearly independent columns of A, choose vectors $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$ such that $Ax_1$ is the first independent coulmn, $Ax_2$ is the second independent and so on. 

Assume $BA = 0$, multiply both sides from the right by $x_1$ you get:
$BAx_1 = 0$, which is an independent solution to $Bx=0$.
Do the same for $x_2,x_3,x_4$ you get 4 different independent solutions, what gives dim solution set of B = 4, but we know dim solution set of B = 2 , contradiction, therefore $BA \neq 0$?

Comment: @Alon, Yes, this reasoning is correct.

Comment: I corrected it from p(B) to dim of solution set of B, now correct?

Comment: Yeah, fine, assuming that 'solution set of B' means 'solution set of $Bx=0$'.

Comment: Ok thank you for the help

Comment: Glad to help you, @Alon.